# Adding elements to an array from a form in a class in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I would like to add elements to an array in a class from a form that will then be populated onto a dropdown later on for selection. My issue is that it only saves the value passed to the form and doesnt hold any previous values passed to it.

Below is the form

```
<form action="settings.php" method="post">
    <label>Add your expenses</label>
    <input type='text' name='expenses'>
    <input type='submit' name='exp' value='ADD!'>
</form>
```

Here is the class to handle inputting the value added from the form

```
class Money {

    public function addExpenses(){
        if(isset($_POST['exp'])){
            $values = $_POST['expenses'];
            $expenses_array = array();
            array_push($expenses_array, $values);
            return $expenses_array;                
        }               
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to save it as an cookie or session array.

Comment: @kmg92, where is your previous values variable, it's is not present inside function

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly why we have sessions.

```
$expenses_array = $_SESSION['expenses_array']??($_SESSION['expenses_array']=array());
```

but know that this only work as long as a session is active, so run `session_start();` first.